# pdo LIKE clause and IN clause

Tags: mysql, pdo

```
$sql = "SELECT id, trader_currency FROM active_trades WHERE status=? AND open_time IN (LIKE ?, LIKE ?, LIKE ?)";

$q = $conn->prepare($sql);

$result = $q->execute(array("Closed", "%".$todayDate."%", "%".$yesterdayDate."%", "%".$last2dayDate."%"));
```

How to combine like clause and in clause in pdo? above code has syntax error.

Comment: you can't use like this way .. update your question add  a proper data sample and the expetced  result  ..  please

Answer (score 1):

Simply by `OR` condition:

```
$sql = 'SELECT id, trader_currency, open_time 
        FROM active_trades 
        WHERE status=?
            AND (
                open_time LIKE ? 
                OR open_time LIKE ? 
                OR open_time LIKE ?
           )';
```

Comment: perfect. Thank you.